# Square root decay of eigenvalues for lower-triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a $d\times d$ matrix with $k$'th row consisting of $k$ constants and the rest 0: $\underbrace{c, c,\ldots,c}_{k},\underbrace{0,\cdots,0}_{d-k}$.Rows are normalized to have norm 1.

IE, for $d=5$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Eigenvalues of this matrix are $\left\{1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right\}$.

What is the easiest way of showing that $k$th eigenvalue is $k^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

<sup><sub>[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-triangular-singularvalues.nb)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the eigenvalues of
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2&a_2\\
a_3&a_3&a_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
a_n&a_n&a_n&\cdots&a_n
\end{pmatrix}$$
are $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n$. This is because
$$\lambda I-M=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda-a_1\\
a_2&\lambda-a_2\\
a_3&a_3&\lambda-a_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
a_n&a_n&a_n&\cdots&\lambda-a_n
\end{pmatrix}$$
has determinant $(\lambda-a_1)\cdots(\lambda-a_n)$, and so the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$.